# Glassfish 2 Server Log

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee, glassfish

The webpage for this application does not open up after the application is run.
The administration console says:

> "An error has occurred -C:/eepassion/UnZip/servletbasics/samples/hello2/build/web"

Thank you for your help.

Please see log info below:

```
Oct 15, 2010 8:27:50 AM com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.launch.ASLauncher buildCommand
INFO: 
C:/Program Files/Sun/SDK/jdk/jre/..\bin\java
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/domains/domain1
-Dcom.sun.aas.ClassPathPrefix=
-Dcom.sun.aas.ClassPathSuffix=
-Dcom.sun.aas.ServerClassPath=
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.appserverChainJars.ee=
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.appserverChainJars=admin-cli.jar,admin-cli-ee.jar,j2ee-svc.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.excludesList=admin-cli.jar,appserv-upgrade.jar,sun-appserv-ant.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.optionalOverrideableChain.ee=
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.optionalOverrideableChain=webservices-rt.jar,webservices-tools.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.serverClassPath.ee=/lib/hadbjdbc4.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/lib/SUNWjdmk/5.1/lib/jdmkrt.jar,/lib/dbstate.jar,/lib/hadbm.jar,/lib/hadbmgt.jar,/lib/mfwk_instrum_tk.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.serverClassPath=C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/lib/install/applications/jmsra/imqjmsra.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/imq/lib/jaxm-api.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/imq/lib/fscontext.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/imq/lib/imqbroker.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/imq/lib/imqjmx.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/lib/SUNWjdmk/5.1/lib/jdmkrt.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.sharedChainJars.ee=appserv-se.jar,appserv-ee.jar,jesmf-plugin.jar,/lib/dbstate.jar,/lib/hadbjdbc4.jar,jgroups-all.jar,/lib/mfwk_instrum_tk.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.classloader.sharedChainJars=javaee.jar,C:/Program Files/Sun/SDK/jdk/jre/../lib/tools.jar,install/applications/jmsra/imqjmsra.jar,com-sun-commons-launcher.jar,com-sun-commons-logging.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/imq/lib/jaxm-api.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/imq/lib/fscontext.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/imq/lib/imqbroker.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/imq/lib/imqjmx.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/imq/lib/imqxm.jar,webservices-rt.jar,webservices-tools.jar,mail.jar,appserv-jstl.jar,jmxremote_optional.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/lib/SUNWjdmk/5.1/lib/jdmkrt.jar,activation.jar,appserv-rt.jar,appserv-admin.jar,appserv-cmp.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/updatecenter/lib/updatecenter.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/jbi/lib/jbi.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/imq/lib/imqjmx.jar,C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar,dbschema.jar
-Dcom.sun.aas.configName=server-config
-Dcom.sun.aas.configRoot=C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/config
-Dcom.sun.aas.defaultLogFile=C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
-Dcom.sun.aas.domainName=domain1
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceName=server
-Dcom.sun.aas.processLauncher=SE
-Dcom.sun.aas.promptForIdentity=true
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.overrideablejavaxpackages=javax.help,javax.portlet
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.taglibs=appserv-jstl.jar,jsf-impl.jar
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.taglisteners=jsf-impl.jar
-Dcom.sun.updatecenter.home=C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/updatecenter
-Ddomain.name=domain1
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/lib/endorsed
-Djava.ext.dirs=C:/Program Files/Sun/SDK/jdk/jre/../lib/ext;C:/Program Files/Sun/SDK/jdk/jre/../jre/lib/ext;C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext;C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/javadb/lib
-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Family\Downloads\glassfish\lib;C:\Users\Family\Downloads\glassfish\lib;C:\Users\Family\Downloads\glassfish\bin;C:\Users\Family\Downloads\glassfish\lib
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/login.conf
-Djava.security.policy=C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.policy
-Djava.util.logging.manager=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ServerLogManager
-Djavax.management.builder.initial=com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.AppServerMBeanServerBuilder
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-Djmx.invoke.getters=true
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
-client
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-Xmx512m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-XX:+LogVMOutput
-XX:LogFile=C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/jvm.log
-cp
C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/lib/jhall.jar;C:\Users\Family\Downloads\glassfish\lib\appserv-launch.jar
com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch
start
Starting Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1 ((v2.1 Patch06)(9.1_02 Patch12)) (build b31g-fcs) ...
CORE5076: Using [Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Version 1.6.0_18] from [Sun Microsystems Inc.]
SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
Using MQ RA for Broker lifecycle control
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: OU=Secure Server Certification Authority, O="RSA Data Security, Inc.", C=US
  Signature Algorithm: MD2withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.2
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1000 bits
  modulus: 6144706769222379850430183405655235862870193813433361902309516534729547168229223442088128897090426025874990958624426272027915771330043379079076269082776443120496525109458437435793974957144923190172655546279112796066635455545786300647745888353781002359412766112775410851780140804282673804950495744761467
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Nov 08 19:00:00 EST 1994,
               To: Thu Jan 07 18:59:59 EST 2010]
  Issuer: OU=Secure Server Certification Authority, O="RSA Data Security, Inc.", C=US
  SerialNumber: [    02ad667e 4e45fe5e 576f3c98 195eddc0]
]
  Algorithm: [MD2withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 65 DD 7E E1 B2 EC B0 E2   3A E0 EC 71 46 9A 19 11  e.......:..qF...
0010: B8 D3 C7 A0 B4 03 40 26   02 3E 09 9C E1 12 B3 D1  ......@&.>......
0020: 5A F6 37 A5 B7 61 03 B6   5B 16 69 3B C6 44 08 0C  Z.7..a..[.i;.D..
0030: 88 53 0C 6B 97 49 C7 3E   35 DC 6C B9 BB AA DF 5C  .S.k.I.>5.l....\
0040: BB 3A 2F 93 60 B6 A9 4B   4D F2 20 F7 CD 5F 7F 64  .:/.`..KM. .._.d
0050: 7B 8E DC 00 5C D7 FA 77   CA 39 16 59 6F 0E EA D3  ....\..w.9.Yo...
0060: B5 83 7F 4D 4D 42 56 76   B4 C9 5F 04 F8 38 F8 EB  ...MMBVv.._..8..
0070: D2 5F 75 5F CD 7B FC E5   8E 80 7C FC 50           ._u_........P
];_RequestID=d747019a-92a7-44a6-8e97-02a8f47e1e23;|SEC5054: Certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: OU=Secure Server Certification Authority, O="RSA Data Security, Inc.", C=US
  Signature Algorithm: MD2withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.2
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1000 bits
  modulus: 6144706769222379850430183405655235862870193813433361902309516534729547168229223442088128897090426025874990958624426272027915771330043379079076269082776443120496525109458437435793974957144923190172655546279112796066635455545786300647745888353781002359412766112775410851780140804282673804950495744761467
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Nov 08 19:00:00 EST 1994,
               To: Thu Jan 07 18:59:59 EST 2010]
  Issuer: OU=Secure Server Certification Authority, O="RSA Data Security, Inc.", C=US
  SerialNumber: [    02ad667e 4e45fe5e 576f3c98 195eddc0]
]
  Algorithm: [MD2withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 65 DD 7E E1 B2 EC B0 E2   3A E0 EC 71 46 9A 19 11  e.......:..qF...
0010: B8 D3 C7 A0 B4 03 40 26   02 3E 09 9C E1 12 B3 D1  ......@&.>......
0020: 5A F6 37 A5 B7 61 03 B6   5B 16 69 3B C6 44 08 0C  Z.7..a..[.i;.D..
0030: 88 53 0C 6B 97 49 C7 3E   35 DC 6C B9 BB AA DF 5C  .S.k.I.>5.l....\
0040: BB 3A 2F 93 60 B6 A9 4B   4D F2 20 F7 CD 5F 7F 64  .:/.`..KM. .._.d
0050: 7B 8E DC 00 5C D7 FA 77   CA 39 16 59 6F 0E EA D3  ....\..w.9.Yo...
0060: B5 83 7F 4D 4D 42 56 76   B4 C9 5F 04 F8 38 F8 EB  ...MMBVv.._..8..
0070: D2 5F 75 5F CD 7B FC E5   8E 80 7C FC 50           ._u_........P
]
SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
WEB0114: SSO is disabled in virtual server [server]
WEB0114: SSO is disabled in virtual server [__asadmin]
JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [3700]
ADM1079: Initialization of AMX MBeans started
ADM1504: Here is the JMXServiceURL for the Standard JMXConnectorServer: [service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://Family-PC.myhome.westell.com:8686/jmxrmi].  This is where the remote administrative clients should connect using the standard JMX connectors
ADM1506: Status of Standard JMX Connector: Active = [true]
JMS Service Connection URL is :mq://Family-PC.myhome.westell.com:7676/
MQJMSRA_RA1101:  Using old JMSRA DIRECT mode
MQJMSRA_RA1101: SJSMQ JMS Resource Adapter starting...
new broker instance constructed ...
Client runtime Starting embedd broker, direct mode enabled=true
MQJMSRA_EB1101: stateChanged:READY : Broker has been started
MQJMSRA_RA1101: SJSMQ JMSRA Started:RADIRECT
LDR5010: All ejb(s) of [MEjbApp] loaded successfully!
EJB5109:EJB Timer Service started successfully for datasource [jdbc/__TimerPool]
LDR5010: All ejb(s) of [__ejb_container_timer_app] loaded successfully!
CORE5048: generated dir is obsolete compared to default-web.xml for application bookstore1; loading from application directory C:/eepassion/tutorial/javaeetutorial5/examples/web/bookstore1/build/web instead.  This takes longer than loading from the generated directory; redeploying the app will recreate the generated directory but is not required.
Not registering AMX MBean against old MBean "com.sun.appserv:j2eeType=WebModule,name=bookstore1,J2EEServer=server,J2EEApplication=null,category=runtime" due to malformed composite WebModule name.
Failed to load deployment descriptor files from directory: C:/Users/Family/Downloads/glassfish/domains/domain1\generated\xml\j2ee-modules\hello2. Load them from directory : C:/eepassion/UnZip/servletbasics/samples/hello2/build/web instead.
LDR5008: ConfigException :
com.sun.enterprise.config.ConfigException: I/O error while loading deployment descriptor for: hello2
cause: C:/eepassion/UnZip/servletbasics/samples/hello2/build/web
        at com.sun.enterprise.instance.WebModulesManager.getDescriptor(WebModulesManager.java:416)
        at com.sun.enterprise.instance.WebModulesManager.getDescriptor(WebModulesManager.java:351)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.DummyWebModuleLoader.(DummyWebModuleLoader.java:71)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.DummyWebModuleManager.getLoader(DummyWebModuleManager.java:63)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.load(AbstractManager.java:202)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLifecycle.onStartup(ApplicationLifecycle.java:221)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:449)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:134)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/eepassion/UnZip/servletbasics/samples/hello2/build/web
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.FileArchive.open(FileArchive.java:79)
        at com.sun.enterprise.instance.BaseManager.openDDArchive(BaseManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.enterprise.instance.WebModulesManager.getDescriptor(WebModulesManager.java:377)
        ... 14 more
CORE5016: Unexpected error occurred while loading applications
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.DummyWebModuleLoader.createRootMBean(DummyWebModuleLoader.java:94)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.load(AbstractManager.java:205)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLifecycle.onStartup(ApplicationLifecycle.java:221)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:449)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:134)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GlassFish couldn't find the deployment descriptor of the application hello2

> com.sun.enterprise.config.ConfigException: I/O error while loading deployment descriptor for: hello2

Which seems to be simply missing

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/eepassion/UnZip/servletbasics/samples/hello2/build/web

Double check the structure of the application you are trying to deploy.

Comment: I followed this path and found the following: 1) web->a)Meta-INF->MANIFEST.MF & ->b)context.xml. 2)web->WEB-INF->a)classes &->b)sun-we.xml &->c)web.xml.  I am unsure what is missing????